# Issue in using jquery.form.wizard.min.js with Grails webflow

Tags: jquery, forms, grails, formwizard

I am using   jquery.form.wizard.min.js [plugin link](https://github.com/thecodemine/formwizard/blob/master/js/jquery.form.wizard.js) to create a wizard based form [Demo](http://www.eakroko.de/flat/forms-wizard.html) i.e I have splitted form in two steps and on second step I submit the form to controller , request params are available on server but not hitting the webflow.If code snippet is required than I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was form plugin, as my application uses many plugin so when I disable jquery form plugin as suggested in [Illustrated example](http://thecodemine.org/examples/example_20_submit_form_without_ajax.html)
my web flow with jquery.form.wizard.min.js working fine